# Intermittent OLAP connection issues from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas

I have a SSAS 2005 cube that has been in production for several years, no changes have been made to it for several months.  Recently a few users, out of many, report getting "An error was encountered in the transport layer." message when they try to refresh cube data in their Excel 2007 pivots.  I can not find any errors on the server in the SQL logs or Window logs.

Doing research on the web I found many articles about improper setups which would have consistent errors but few on intermittent connection issues and the ones I did find had no answers.

For now I have been having the users reboot but that is not a good long term solution.  I have a feeling it is an network issue but I don't want to get into the finger pointing game with the network folks without something concrete.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: An error message with "transport layer" in it would immediately lead me to the hardware side.

Comment: @jbarker2160 I agree with you but I am looking for more then "I think its the network"  This has happened on different PC with different users so if it is a hardware issue it is on the network side not PC side.  That said, I am not aware of any issues with the network for any other application just this one.  If its the network I need to give the network guys a direction to look in.

Comment: I meant that the traffic isn't leaving the PC.  My mistake.  I meant software.